# Copy with Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I try to run the Angular app inside docker with Nginx:

```
$ ls
dist  Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx

COPY ./dist/statistic-ui /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Inside `dist/statistic-ui/` all app files.

But `COPY` command doesn't work, Nginx just starts with default welcome page and when I check files inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/` only default Nginx files.

Why `COPY` command doesn't work and how to fix it?

**UPDATE**
Run docker container

```
sudo docker run -d --name ui -p 8082:80 nginx
```

Comment: How are you building and running the image?

Comment: Try /dist/statistic-ui/, with a trailing slash. If a path ends with a slash, it will be considered a directory and its contents will be copied.

Comment: @David Maze add run command to question

Comment: @Burak Serdar I change to `COPY ./dist/statistic-ui/ usr/share/nginx/html/` but same result

Comment: You need to build before you run. The `run` command uses whatever image already exists. If you update `Dockerfile` you must build a new version of that image prior to `run`.

Comment: ./dist/statistic-ui/ is a symlink by any change? Or ./dist/ a symlink?

Comment: If you're running `nginx`, you're running the nginx container, not the container you built

Comment: @Burak Serdar this help I forget. Thank you just start with docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an image from your Dockerfile then run a container from that image:

```
docker build -t angularapp .
docker run -d --name ui -p 8082:80 angularapp
```

> Make sure you include the trailing dot at the end of the docker build command.